# Ruby and Rails gem install issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Im learning ruby on rails for a module and class and following a tutorial.
When I try to install a gem like this: gem simple-navigation (or gem "simple-navigation")
I get this error

> ERROR while executing gem ... (Gem:CommandLineError)
>
> > unknown command simple-navigation

This happens with all gems. gem install simple-navigation works, however doesnt install when i run bundle install. I have to manually add it to the gemfile to get it to work.

Anyone know why this is happening? Using Ruby 2.00 and Rails 4

Comment: Should it not be `gem install simple-navigation` not `gem simple-navigation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended behavior. `gem install simple-navigation` will work correctly to install a gem for *ruby*, but to install a gem for your *rails* application, you need to add the gem to your Gemfile and then run `bundle install` instead of just running the `gem install` command.

You are getting the error you posted because you are running `gem simple-navigation`, and that is not a command.