# unable to run a gem through terminal

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I uploaded my first gem into rubygems.  The code is tested and the gemspec is fine.  It is in rubygems and rubydoc.  I installed it on my machine via `gem install [gem_name]`. `gem list` lists it.  However `[gem_name]` command yields `gem_name: command not found`.

YET: `gem '[gem_name]','~>[version_num]'` yields: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command gem_name,~>version_num`

(aside: I could've sworn when I first published I played with it and `gem_name` worked flawlessly to run my gem...)

what can I do to diagnose this problem?  Please advise.

**EDIT:** `require '[gem_name]'` works flawlessly in IRB.  It runs smoothly (interacts with user). Once finished, it returns `true`.  When I require other gems, eg `require '[another_gem]'` true is returned immediately.  The code doesn't actually run.  Perhaps this shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

`gem gem_name` or `gem_name` is not a command. If you are trying to check if the gem installed properly, try `gem_name -v`. Also, depends on what flags and args your gem takes.

You are getting that error because`gem gem_name` is not a command.

For eg: You do a `gem install rails`. Then you don't just do `gem rails` to run it. You do `rails some_command` or flag, etc. Like `rails new blog`.

Comment: I am using `gem_name` in place of my real gem name (so I don't get accused of advertising my gem) I tried `gem_name -v`. It yielded: `gem_name: command not found`.

Comment: i know. :) `gem yourgem` is not a command. That is not how gems work. Something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621794/ruby-and-rails-gem-install-issues

Comment: gem 'gem_name','~>version_num' is for the gemspec.  My gem is listed under `gem list`.  I was previously running my gem (once installed) simply by typing `gem_name` where `gem_name` = `the words I name my gem`   I read your supplied link.  I have already successfully installed my gem on my machine via `gem install [gem_name]`.

Comment: @foo can you try in irb: `require 'yourgem'` ? What does it return?

Comment: @foo Also, did you bundle any binary or executable in your gem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186149/discussion-between-aaditya-maheshwari-and-foo).

Answer (score 0):

Do other gems run properly? If not, the issue may be with your path. If you run the gem from the folder it is located in, does it still yield problems? Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I considered that.  I installed a couple of gems and they worked without a hitch.  Then I uninstalled/reinstalled my gem. Very perplexed.  I **remember** it worked fine after original installation.  [gem_name] and it ran (it takes 0 command line args).  I also tried ~/my/path/to/my_gem [my_gem] and nothing...but this should not matter... all other gems I installed I can run from anywhere in terminal.  my_gem is also listed in `gem list`...idk? perplexed!

Comment: Are you sure your original program ran correctly? Even if it didn’t it should still show up as a command, but it is worth asking.

Comment: Yes.  I test/played with it **a lot** (my first gem how can I resist).  And it **is** under `gem list`.  It is also in rubygems and rubydoc (which is very slow to upload).

Comment: I don’t know why/how this would happen, but the problem may be with your system. Do you have access to another system to download the gem on and test it?

Comment: fyi gem runs in irb through `require` .  It asks user for input, and eventually returns true.